# How to creating master tables and insert defaults value while installing C#, SQL Server, Windows application

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, deployment

I am developing POS SQL Server & C# application in Visual Studio. I want to deploy it to client-server such a way that it automatically install on the client machine. Which is the best way to create the database, stored procedures, views,  tables, and insert some default values in the client's SQL Server at the end of the installation?

Is running SQL statements, one by one, using C# efficient? Or should I be restoring from a sample copy of the database?

Comment: Are you using any kind of ORM tool.?

Answer (score 0):

Best bay is restoring the database. You can also take complete script of database and run the script instead of executing individual script. I will put how you can do it

- Right click on database
- Go to **Tasks** then **generate scripts**
- Select **Select entire database**
- Script has to saved to a folder.
- Use this script to create and restore database.

Comment: is there any way to execute entire script without looping

Comment: foreach (string sql in Createsql)
                {
                    if (sql.Length > 30)
                    {

                      
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                }

looping one by one?

Answer (score 0):

From the SQL Server Management Studio you can right click on your database and select:

1. Tasks -> Generate Scripts
2. Then simply proceed through the wizard.
3. In "Set Scripting Options" -> Click on Advanced -> Types of data to
           script -> Select "Schema and Data"
4. Select Location And simply proceed through the wizard.